# How to have excel show you what numbers are not 0 out in a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2010. I am reconciling bank statements with at least 3200 checks.  I color checks that came thru bank and intersperse the checkbook in a single column . Then I go thru column to see what check does not 0 out. For example:

```
10105   -199.41                 
10105   199.41                  
10106   -353.98                 
10106   353.98                  
10107   -730.19                 
10107   730.19                  
10108   -654.77                 
10108   654.77                  
**10109 351.83  **I will pick this check out because it is notcleared 
10110   -392.40
10110   392.40
10111   -422.53
10111   422.53
10112   -464.85
10112   464.85
```

Thank you so much for your help. I know there has to be an easier way

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't put personal contact information in your posts. All communication will be done here or in chat. Also, we are not a service site, so we need to know what you have already attempted to resolve this on your own and where you are stuck. From there we can help you find a solution. This site is not designed to do it for you. Reading ***[ask]*** may help explain things better.

Comment: Your task would be much simpler if you enter the offsetting amount in the adjacent column for the same record rather than entering a new record.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are multiple ways to go about this so I will give you a quick one that should give you an easier time locating the checks that haven't cleared yet. First things first you want to make use of the "Substitute" function in excel to make a new column that copy's from your first column. So lets say your data is laid out as you described and everything is in column A starting at the first row, this is what you need to do.

In column B beside each line that has any data you would enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")
```

Of course you would replace "A1" with whatever line you are on so if you are on the 3rd row then the formula would look like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","")
```

What this formula does is remove the "-" from the line so that we can check the line for duplicates and there for find unique values.

After that is done you would select the entire column B and then go to the "home" tab in Excel and in the middle somewhere look for the button that says "Conditional Formatting" click that and select "Highlight Cell Rules" then in that list select "Duplicate Values" then a window will pop up, there's a drop down button that says "Duplicate" Select that and change it to "Unique" then hit ok. Now all the cells that are highlighted with red are cells that are "Unique" and there for they are checks that haven't cleared.

Here's an Image of that it looks like on my computer:

[image]

Note that if your data is in two separate columns you will need to use a formula that first combines the two columns and then removes the dashes. So something like this place in column C:

```
=SUBSTITUTE((A1&B1),"-","")
```

Where "A1" is where the check number is stored and "B1" is where the check value is stored.

Hopefully something in here helps.